# Postgresql - update rows or delete on unique constraint violation

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a many-to-many table 'permit_role' as below:

| permit_id | role_id |
| --- | --- |
| permit_1 | role_1 |
| permit_2 | role_1 |
| permit_3 | role_3 |
| permit_4 | role_1 |
| permit_4 | role_2 |

---

It has a unique constraint `(permit_id, role_id)`.

I need to update permits as below:

permit_1 --> permit_5

permit_2 --> permit_5

So it`s impossible to do just

```
UPDATE permit_role SET permit_id = 'permit_5' WHERE permit_id = 'permit_1';

UPDATE permit_role SET permit_id = 'permit_5' WHERE permit_id = 'permit_2';
```

because I`ll got a unique constraint violation (two rows with (permit_5, role_1)).
In this case I need the duplicated rows just to be deleted so I have only one such row in the end.

I thought about temp tables but it seems to difficult, please advise what is the easiest way to achieve my goal.

Comment: Interesting question. I think a trigger can do the trick.

Comment: Trigger is not an option, I need to do it with an SQL-script

Comment: If you have a unique constraint and you want to change permit 1 / 2 to 5 just update one of them and delete the other, wouldn't that work ?

Comment: Yeah, but I need more general solution because there could be hundreds of such diffent permits :) Laurenz`s solution below works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a CTE:

```
WITH old_rows AS (
   DELETE FROM permit_role
   WHERE permit_id = 'permit_1'
   RETURNING role_id
)
INSERT INTO permit_role (permit_id, role_id)
SELECT 'permit_5', role_id
FROM old_rows
ON CONFLICT (permit_id, role_id) DO NOTHING;
```

Then repeat for `permit_2`. The `ON CONFLICT` clause will keep you from inserting duplicates without getting an error.